# Remove timezone in SQL Server query while keeping the precision

Tags: sql-server, timezone, timezone-offset

I am running the following query on SQL Server 2019:

```
SELECT
    autoid,
    ReceivedUTC,
    ReceivedUTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' AS ReceivedTST
FROM 
    "EPOMCAFEE_Events".dbo."EPOEvents" t
```

From which I get the following (sample) results:

```
autoid   ReceivedUTC              ReceivedTST
----------------------------------------------------------------
606416  2022-09-26 16:36:53.960   2022-09-26 18:36:53.960 +02:00
606415  2022-09-26 16:36:53.960   2022-09-26 18:36:53.960 +02:00
```

How can I remove the timezone part (" +02:00"), while keeping the precision (".960"), in my column ReceivedTST ?

Best regards

Altin

Comment: Just curious - but why do you need to remove the time zone offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove the offset is to CAST the `datetimeoffset` value to datetime2(3):

```
SELECT
    autoid,
    ReceivedUTC,
    CAST(ReceivedUTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time' AS datetime2(3)) AS ReceivedTST
FROM 
    "EPOMCAFEE_Events".dbo."EPOEvents" t;
```

Comment: Thank You Dan Guzman.